# Does this Wild Magic result affect the sorcerer or just other creatures?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, wild-magic

A result of 75 or 76 on the Wild Magic Surge table triggers this effect:

> You glow with bright light in a 30-foot radius for the next minute. Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of you is blinded until the end of its next turn.

Does this blindness affect the sorcerer who triggered the surge (since she will always be within 5' of herself?

Or are only *other* creatures affected by it?

Comment: Interesting thing, this would even blind you if a wall was between you and the other creature because it doesn't have the "that can see you" part.

Comment: @findusl That may be worth another question. But i'm not sure how the light would extend past a wall. This isn't like a Paladin's magical aura.

Comment: @NautArch Well to be fair, it IS wild magic...

Comment: Great.  Now I'm picturing a wild mage trying to hide, completely unaware that the hallway on the other side of the wall has a patch of light apparently emanating from the wall.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Most likely only other creatures

This is similar to Aura effects in that:

> You glow with bright light in a 30-foot radius for the next minute

While this doesn't use the word 'aura', the mechanical effect is similar in that you are the effect emanates from you in a specific radius. If we utilize this mechanical similarity, we can look at other Aura effects or spell effects with similar mechanics.

These **all** have different language in how the aura works that state (pulling from Paladin's [Aura of Protection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/paladin)):

> whenever you or a friendly creature within 10 feet of you...

*[Aura of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-life)* also has differing language that states:

> Each nonhostile creature in the aura (including you)

Every mechanic that involves something emanating from yourself includes langauge like the above. I have yet to find any mechanic that shows otherwise.

### But it's awful wording

Reading it as-is does seem like you count. The only reasoning I've got otherwise I have above, but in a vacuum the blindness would extend to you. However, the support I've given above does strongly suggest that you aren't included by the absence of language that includes yourself.

Answer (score 17):

Only other creatures are affected by this, because the rule does not state that you are affected; only other creatures within 5 feet of you.

> You glow with bright light in a 30-foot radius for the next minute. Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of you is blinded until the end of its next turn.

Unlike the result of 95-96, it explicitly states that you *are* affected (emphasis mine):

> 95-96. **You and all creatures within 30 feet** of you gain vulnerability to piercing damage for the next minute.

The general rule of thumb is that if a rule does not state something, than it does not include that thing. In this case, it would state that *you* are also blinded. Since the rule does not state this, you are unaffected.

Comment: I like that you provided evidence from within the same table, this strengthens the argument; +1

Comment: It is reverse. The effect would have to establish that you are exempt from the radius of creatures that forms an n-sphere on which you are the point of origin of the diameter. Note that your analogy is faulty because it doesn't use the radius terminology.

Comment: @Akixkisu The radius is about the light effect, not the blind effect, and besides there's nothing magical about the word radius that triggers some different logic. That's not how 5e is written.

Comment: "*the rule does not state that you are affected*" But it does. It says "*Any creature that ...*". Surely you are a creature.

Comment: The operative word is "you". As I have pointed out in the next excerpt "*You* and all creatures".

Answer (score 8):

### She is affected.

> 75-76 You glow with bright light in a 30-foot radius for the next minute.
>   Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of you is blinded until
>   the end of its next turn.

She is a creature within a radius of 5 feet (0 even, she is the point of origin) and she will be blinded. She isn't exempt from effects unless the description states otherwise. If someone casts [fireball](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) on themselves, they will be affected. A radius effect always includes the point of origin, unless it is explicitly stated otherwise. The effect would have to establish that you are exempt from the radius of creatures that forms an n-sphere on which you are the point of origin of the diameter.

A radius is a well-established term, and it includes the point of origin and the diameter of the shape. Further, it is well-defined what in that radius is affected: all creatures are affected. You are a creature, and no further text is required that specifies this.

For all purposes, it is phrased like a **Sphere** (PHB 204):

> You select a sphere’s point of origin, and the sphere extends outward
>   from that point. The sphere’s size is expressed as a radius in feet
>   that extends from the point. A sphere’s point of origin is included in
>   the sphere’s area of effect.

A sphere’s point of origin is included in the sphere’s area of effect. This is also true for aura type of effects which have the [person as the point of origin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129394/44723), and when you compare it to other rolls on the Wild Magic Surge table (PHB 104):

> 95-96. You and all creatures within 30 feet of you gain vulnerability
>   to piercing damage for the next minute.

You will notice that the wording is distinct. It makes this explicit that the 95-96 roll doesn't use a radius and indeed would have to establish that you are included in that effect, and it does exactly that.

The 69-70 roll would not affect her because it doesn't establish that it uses a radius or that you are affected.

> 69-70 Each creature within 30 feet of you becomes invisible for the
>   next minute. The invisibility ends on a creature when it attacks or
>   casts a spell.

Compare moreover how the 89-80 invisibility effect is also distinctively worded that you are affected, not creatures within a radius or creatures within x feet of you:

> 89-90 You become invisible for the next minute. During that
>   time, other creatures can’t hear you. The invisibility ends if you
>   attack or cast a spell.

Comment: If I'm understanding, your answer is that, because the keyword "radius" is featured in the effect's description, it obeys the rules for a sphere AoE. Other effects on the table, which lack the "radius" keyword, need to clarify that the sorcerer is included in the AoE because of this keyword omission. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: You're saying "Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of you" counts the caster and "Each creature within 30 feet of you" doesn't? Why on earth would that be?

Comment: @Rykara yes. The logical phrasing is that the light causes the blinding effect by context - if these were two separate effects, then only the light would have the radius, and she would not be blinded (because the blinding effect has no radius and would have to state, that it indeed affects her). So my ruling hinges on the light to establish the radius as the source of the blinding effect. 69-70  measures distance and doesn't establish a radius. Distance does not include the point of origin. (Unless it specifies that which _Inspiring Leader_ does; see PHB 167).

Comment: @Zeus Going to add that in, when I have time to clarify that for people who are confused about why it may seem like I rule two different things, for the moment - my comment has to suffice.

Comment: @Akixkisu The distance of the blindness effect isn't even the same as the radius of the light. The radius *is* 30 feet, which is different from area of the blindness effect. Saying the word "radius" applies even though the distance is different makes no sense, and doesn't matter because again there's nothing magical about the word radius that makes it include the caster. Otherwise the text in sphere would be redundant.

Comment: @Akixkisu If anything, the wording of sphere indicates the opposite, because it specifically calls out the origin as being part of the effect, and the wild surge does not.

Answer (score 1):

### **The caster is definitively not affected.**

The wild magic result in question says:

> 75-76 You glow with bright light in a 30-foot radius for the next minute. Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of you is blinded until the end of its next turn.

There are 2 effects being mentioned in this result:

Sentence 1 states a bright light is created.  That has a stated radius effect centered on the caster.

Sentence 2 states that any creature within 5 feet of you is blinded.  It does not state that the caster is affected by this blinding effect.  Using other entries from this table as a comparison:

***Affected:***

> 89-90 **You become invisible** for the next minute. During that time, other creatures can’t hear you. The invisibility ends if you attack or cast a spell.

and

> 95-96. **You and all creatures within 30 feet of you** gain vulnerability to piercing damage for the next minute.

***Not affected:***

> 69-70 **Each creature within 30 feet of you** becomes invisible for the next minute. The invisibility ends on a creature when it attacks or casts a spell.

I fully grant that this last one is an odd effect, but if you're expecting sense from a wild mage you're more likely to get potato soup.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first answer!